# Why do some processes pass on their cpu usage to another process when it ends?

Tags: bash, process

I have wondered this for a while.

For example, lets say `process1` is a process that uses a lot of cpu power, like 90%. Its a video game. Then i have `process2` which uses 10-12% cpu. Its a web browser.

When i quit `process1`, `process2`s cpu power suddenly becomes 90% just like `process1`s  cpu usage used to be. And after a few seconds it goes back to normal cpu usage like 10-12%.

Comment: What is the other process in this scenario? This jumping around by processes is called context switching and there's a fair amount going on there. It's likely that process2 was ready to run, and so it gained access to the CPU for that 90% duration and then was done with its CPU intensive work, and was context switched out by the Kernel afterwards.

Comment: Its a web browser.

Comment: So perhaps some page in a tab has an active element that needed to be refreshed. You'd have to run the process in `strace` to see what it was actually up to, or attach `gdb` to it, to know for sure.

Comment: The Linux Kernel is very Good at doing what slm said.  Another Hallmark is [Kernel Preemption](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/Preemption), which also may be occurring.  Forgive the Reference to Windows, but [here is a very good document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx) on processes and threads.

Comment: Im not in Linux though. Im using Darwin.

Comment: The Concepts are the same regardless of OS. [Context Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) has been in Windows since 95, IIRC, and Preemption has existed since NT4.

Comment: I understand. Ok :).

Comment: Modern systems also slow the CPU clock down when not very busy to save energy. This automatically means that a given amount of processing will use relatively more CPU.